# Show that either $\mu(S) = 0$ or $\mu(G \setminus S) = 0$

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $H \leq G$ be a dense subgroup  and **$\mu$** be a Haar measure.

Let $S \subseteq G$ be a measurable subset such that for each $h \in H$ the sets $hS \cap (G \setminus S)$ and $S \cap (G \setminus hS)$ are both null-sets.

Then, show that either $\mu(S) = 0$ or $ \mu(G \setminus S) = 0$.

Any help with this question!

Answer (score 0):

Fix a measurable subset $S$ in $G$, let $1_S$ denote the indicator function.

Since $1_S\in L^\infty(G)$ we can think about it as a functional on $L^1(G)$ given by 
$$1_S (f) = \int_G 1_S(x) f(x)dx=\int_S f(x)dx$$

By assumption we have for every $h\in H$ that

$$\int_G 1_S(hx)f(x)dx-\int_G 1_S(x)f(x)dx = \int_G (1_S(hx)-1_S(x))f(x)dx=0$$
We explain the last equality:

$1_S(hx)-1_S(x)\not=0$ if and only if $x\in S\cap G\backslash hS$ or $x\in hS\cap G\backslash S$, By assumptions we have those are of measure zero. Hence the last equality follows.

We conclude that $$\int_G 1_S(x)f(h^{-1}x)dx=\int_G 1_S(hx)f(x)dx = \int_G 1_S(x)f(x)dx$$
where the first equation is just a change of variables.

Now the map $g\mapsto \int_S f(g^{-1}x) dx$ is continuous and trivial on $H$ hence trivial. Choosing $f$ wisely you would have that $\mu(S)=0,1$.